# Access of undefined properties in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm following tutorial here

http://www.graphicsxone.com/checkbox-and-as3-in-flash-cs4.html

This is my code in main.as

```
package {

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        // import the CheckBox class
        import fl.controls.CheckBox;    
        mport flash.events.*;

    public class main extends Sprite {      

        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init ); 

        // create the CheckBoxes
        var NS = new CheckBox();
        var SS = new CheckBox();
        var ES = new CheckBox();
        var WS = new CheckBox();

    }

  private function init( e:Event ):void
  {
    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
    response_txt.text = 'foo bar baz etc';
  } 

}
```

When I test it says

Access of undefined properties response_txt.

New picture http://img217.imageshack.us/i/responsetxt2.jpg/

[image]

Comment: Is this all on frame 1?  We can't see your timeline in the current picture.  Also, is that directly on the main timeline, or is it nested inside another clip?  Can you show us your heirarchy?

Comment: I cannot upload it so see http://img217.imageshack.us/i/responsetxt2.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never instantiated response_txt.

```
var response_txt:TextField = new TextField();
response_txt.text = "blah blah blah";
```

That or you aren't assigning the instance name properly in the flash IDE. I didn't look at the tutorial much but - if your symbol is on the stage, just click on it and be sure to give it the right instance name...

Comment: I did assign an instance name see my picture above

Comment: hrm. Thats weird. Somethings borked somewhere. Have you tried to add that textfield programmatically? I know you're trying to get a tute to work, but it might help you find the issue...

Comment: finally my init was never called because I didn't have constructor :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an instance of response_txt.

From tutorial:

> Take the Text Tool and draw a
>   rectangle to cover the inside of the
>   container.
>
> Set the Text property in the
>   Properties to “Dynamic text” with a
>   instance name of **response_txt**.

Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple issue, `response_txt` exists on the stage, but the stage hasn't been instantiated when the code is called.

The simple solution is to add an event handler in the class constructor:

```
import flash.events.Event;

public class main extends Sprite
{
  public function main():void
  {
    addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
  }

  private function init( e:Event ):void
  {
    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );
    response_txt.text = 'foo bar baz etc';
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code see above but it still output same error did I make something wrong again ?

Comment: That should work assuming you didn't make a typo in the naming, and that it's on the first frame of the timeline.

Comment: Yes it's on first frame and I copy and paste the name from property to editor!

Comment: I also added import flash.events.* that was missing in my code.